# Android onClickListener not working in compound view

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener, android-imagebutton

I have a compound view with following xml and code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/attachment"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_attach"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:hint="@string/chatBoxHint"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_send"/>

</merge>
```

Code:

```
public class TextUserInputView extends LinearLayout implements View.OnClickListener{
    private EditText mMessage;

    public TextUserInputView(Context context){
        super(context);
        inflateView(context);
    }

    public TextUserInputView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)    {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflateView(context);
    }

    public TextUserInputView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        inflateView(context);
    }

    private void inflateView(Context context){
        // set default attribute values
        setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
        setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        int padding = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.padding_default);
        setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
        setLayoutParams(params);
        // inflate layout.
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.user_input_text, this);
        addListeners();
    }

    private void addListeners(){
        mMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
        final ImageButton attachment = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.attachment);
        final ImageButton send = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.send);
        mMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
            {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s))
                {
                    send.setEnabled(false);
                } else
                {
                    send.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });

        attachment.setOnClickListener(this);
        attachment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        send.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.send)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.attachment)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The view is being inflated from the xml into an Activity.

The on click listener on the **Send** button is never being called.
Can anyone find out the reason? Maybe the code just needs some fresh eyes.

Comment: Show all the related XMLs. You're sharing layout for a custom view which has merge tag, and you're not even inflating that layout in the java file.

Comment: Thanks @Jabbar_Jigariyo. 
I was inflating the view correctly. 
I found the error. The problem trivial. It was due to another transparent view hiding this view.

Answer (score 0):

I know that you just found the solution and the question is kinda old but I wanted to write this answer to make it more cleaner:
If you remove the following two attrs : (android:clickable="true",android:focusable="true")  from the last nested view which is the ImageView,
it will work.
By making the ImageView clickable and focusable it intercepts the event and dosen't let the parent get the event click :/
That's it.
And thanks for reading